# JavaScript compare behavior

Tags: javascript

How internally JavaScript compare?

```
alert(022 > "21"); // false
alert(22 > "21"); // true
alert("22" > "21"); // true
```

I was reading one article [here](http://javascript.info/tutorial/string#highlighter_18828), and it looks that according to that the first should be `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, any numeric literal starting with `0` is considered as an octal number. So

```
console.log(022);
# 18
```

That is why `console.log(022 > "21");` evaluates to `false`.

If you want to know how comparing these two entities work, please check the [ECMA 5.1 standard specification for The Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.8.5)

Answer (score 0):

Checking that strings are integers is separate to comparing..

See this link: [Javascript string/integer comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630123/javascript-string-integer-comparisons)