# Recursive function for child DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to use a recursive function to show/hide multiple nested UL/LI elements on the DOM.

I have a function which works for single nested, but I am trying to use a recursive function to control an *x* amount of nested elements.

Here is what I currently have:

HTML

```
<section data-range="true">
  <input type="range">
  <ul>
    <li>Item one</li>
    <li>Item two</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Nestd two-one</li>
      <li>Nestd two-two</li>
      <ul>
        <li>Double-nested one</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
    <li>Item three</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

JS:

```
/*  eventListener
 *  Attach an event listener to this element
 *
 *  @param Object - Event object
*/
function eventListener(el) {
  el.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      // List
      else if (el.parentNode.children[1].nodeName == "UL" || el.parentNode.children[1].nodeName == "OL") {
          updateList(e, el.value);
      }
  });
}

/*  updateList
 *
 *  @param Object - Event object
 *  @param Real - Range value (i.e. 3.2)
*/
function updateList(e, range) {
    var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    var list = target.nextSibling.nextElementSibling;
    var listNumber = list.childElementCount;

    displayChildren(list, listNumber);
}

/*  displayChildren
 *
 *  @param Object - Event object
*/
function displayChildren(list, listNumber) {

    for (var i = 0; i < listNumber; i++) {
        if (list.children[i].nodeName != 'UL') {
            list.children[i].style.display = (list.children[i].getAttribute('data-position') <= range) ? "":"none";
        }
        if (list.children[i].children.length > 0) {
            displayChildren(list.children[i], list.children[i].childElementCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some live examples:

- [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/mabikunure/1/edit?js,output) with recursive function on nested elements.
- [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/gogemorone/edit?js,output) with working nested elements.

Any helpful tips are appreciated.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you are trying to accomplish.  Please show or describe before/after results so we can see exactly what you start with and what you want to end with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you just omit some parameters. :)

Check it [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/nilepiheqi/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
function updateList(e, range) {
  ...
  displayChildren(list, listNumber, range); // add range param.
}

function displayChildren(list, listNumber, range) { // and here
  ...
  displayChildren(list.children[i], list.children[i].childElementCount, range); // and here.
```

Why don't use jQuery? anyway, It's cool script you've made, good luck :)

---- EDIT

Your data-position and input range's values are not 'Number', they are 'String'.

So, If more then 10 'UL' elements it compares like '10' with '4' (and '4' is bigger value')

[JsBin (working demo)](http://jsbin.com/mosafejipe/edit?html,js,output)

to fix it, convert to number type before compare them at

```
function eventListener(el) {
  ...
  updateList(e, parseInt(el.value));


function displayChildren(list, listNumber, range) {
  ...
  // Now range is Number. (and LHS will converted with number)
  list.children[i].style.display = (list.children[i].getAttribute('data-position') <= range) ? "":"none";
```

I think you already got it, check it out :) [Javascript string/integer comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630123/javascript-string-integer-comparisons)

---- Edit again

And.. If you just want to show and hide 'LI' elements how about this?

```
var Range = function(step) {
  var rangeElements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-range]");

  for(var i = 0; i < rangeElements.length; i++) {
    var el = rangeElements[i];
    var inputRange = el.children[0]; // input type="range"
    var sectionRange = el.children[1]; // root UL

    inputRange.min = 0;
    inputRange.max = inputRange.value = sectionRange.getElementsByTagName('LI').length;
    inputRange.step = Number(step) || 1;

    // for better UX use oninput event.
    inputRange.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
      var el = e.target;
      var rangeItems = el.parentNode.children[1].getElementsByTagName('LI');
      var range = Number(el.value);
      for(var i = 0; i < rangeItems.length; i++) { rangeItems[i].style.display = i < range ? '' : 'none'; }
    });
  }
  return rangeElements;
}
```

Comment: And it is better, consider hide 'UL' element when there's no visible 'LI' children.

Comment: Thanks! It's always something little like this... Anyway, this project is open-source on GitHub as well

Comment: Strange, there's still a bug with this when adding more LI nested elements in HTML