# Custom pipe doesn't work properly in Angular2

Tags: sorting, angular, angular2-pipe

The pipe has to sort an array of objects by the `name` property.

**sort-by.pipe.ts:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'sortBy'
})
export class SortByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  private name: string;

  transform(array: Array<any>, args: string[]): Array<any> {
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a.name < b.name) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a.name > b.name) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
 <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let elem of _values | sortBy">
      <td>{{ elem.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ elem.ts }}</td>
      <td>{{ elem.value }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
//other imports
import { SortByPipe } from './sort-by.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SortByPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**The array of objects:**

```
[{
  "name": "t10",
  "ts": 1476778297100,
  "value": "32.339264",
  "xid": "DP_049908"
}, {
  "name": "t17",
  "ts": 1476778341100,
  "value": "true",
  "xid": "DP_693259"
}, {
  "name": "t16",
  "ts": 1476778341100,
  "value": "true",
  "xid": "DP_891890"
}];
```

It doesn't sort the objects properly, but also doesn't throw any errors. 
Maybe there's something wrong with my files?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Maybe what you want is to do an integer compare..  Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630123/javascript-string-integer-comparisons

Comment: are you expecting the order to be `'t10', 't16', 't17'`?

Comment: @ps2goat Yes my friend

Comment: I think the problem is in you "ngFor" you are pipin the elements.. not the array

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are piping the elements and not the array itself.

You should change this

```
<tr *ngFor="let elem of _values | sortBy">
```

to this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let elem of (_values | sortBy)">
```

Comment: @H.Doe whats the result that you are getting?

Comment: It just doesnt sort the array. But I think that the problem is lying somewhere else. The sorting function which ive implemented basically doesnt work. It doesnt sort these properties at all.

Comment: I've tested the sort function with the data you posted and works fine for me. Maybe you can put some `console.log`'s to see what happens or even better, debug it.

Comment: When I `console.log` the variable its still unsorted.

Comment: This works, previously I had an issue that the _values weren't passed to my pipe filter function. This does exactly that! Sounds like others have an issue with their pipe filter function. 
<tr *ngFor="let elem of (_values | search: searchTerm)">

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `pure: false`?

This makes it so that Angular doesn't care if the input is changed or not

```
@Pipe({
  name: "sort",
  pure: false
})
```