# How to check if 2017-03-29T06:45:00.000Z is equal to the date and time now?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a date with the format 2017-03-29T06:45:00.000Z, how do I check if it is equal or less to the date and time now?

If I check with

```
var currentTime = new Date();
if("2017-03-29T06:45:00.000Z" <= currentTime){
```

its not right since current date is in the format `Wed Mar 29 2017 08:59:18 GMT+0200(CEST)`
Any input appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please add the language tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compare a string to a `Date` Object. Because the two data types do not match, javascript tries to compare them by their value and calls `currentTime.valueOf()`. This evaluates to a integer like `1490781568805`. Javascript then tries to compare the string to the evaluated integer. The result is [different than you might expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630493/2752278), because the individual char codes of the string are compared to the integer.

```
"2017-03-29T06:45:00.000Z" <= new Date() // string compared to the Date object
"2017-03-29T06:45:00.000Z" <= new Date().valueOf() // javascript trying get a value for the date object
"2017-03-29T06:45:00.000Z" <= 1490781568805 // evaluates to false
```

You can just parse your date string to a Date object using `Date.parse()`

```
Date.parse("2017-03-29T06:45:00.000Z") <= new Date() // two Date objects are compared
```

Comment: ... assuming your used language is javascript