# Vue : Table filter on column name with condition

Tags: javascript, object, search, vue.js

I have the following code to filter the table. I select a column from drop-down like `age` then selects operator from another drop-down like `<` and search input like `20`, And want to search table on them.

Filter :

```
// Select column name
<select class="dv-header-select" v-model="query.search_column">
    <option v-for="column in columns" :value="column">{{column}}</option>
</select>

// Select condition(<,>,<=,>=) 
<select class="dv-header-select" v-model="query.search_operator">
    <option v-for="(value, key) in operators" :value="key">{{value}}</option>
</select>

// Search value
<input type="text" class="dv-header-input" placeholder="Search"
    v-model="query.search_input">
```

Please read the code comments in JS section to get the idea.

```
  <tr v-for="row in getSearchedRow">
      <td v-for="(value, key) in row">{{value}}</td>
  </tr>
```

JS:

```
  data() {
    return {
    model: { data: [] },
    // populating on API call
    columns: {},
    query: {
        search_column: 'id',
        search_operator: 'equal',
        search_input: ''
    }
  },

  getSearchedRow: function() {

    return this.model.data.filter(row => {
      let value = row[this.query.search_column];
      for(var key in row){
        if(String(row[key]).indexOf(this.query.search_input) !== -1){

          // Return true required to populate table
          if(this.query.search_column.length < 1) {
            return true;
          }

          // when condition gets here, The table shows 0 records
          if(this.query.search_operator == 'less_than') {
            return value < this.query.search_input;
          }

        }
      }
    });
  }
```

The table get populated because of first `if()` but shows empty on second `if()`.

What am i missing ?

Comment: What are the actual values of `value` and `this.query.search_input` at that point? Could it maybe be that you're trying to compare the two as numbers but they're actually strings?  Famous `"2">"10"` returns `true` in Javascript.

Comment: @sjaustirni the value of `value` is the selected table column values. currently Like i have three row only, When you select a column e.g id, then the values are `22`,`23`,`24`..... And the `this.query.search_input` is the search string i want to search, E.g selected column from dropdown is `age` and the selected condition from dropdown is `>` and the `this.query.search_input` is 20.

Comment: Would you make sure that both variables are numbers by parsing the `string`s to `int` and report back whether it helped anything? This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630123/javascript-string-integer-comparisons

Comment: Nope it isn't working for both `string` and `int`

Comment: Hmm. I don't see where it could go wrong there, with my lack of knowledge of context. Would you put up an MCVE example of this behaviour?

Comment: Updating the question.

Comment: @sjaustirni Question uptdated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate over each key of your objects and test if they partially match the desired value. You probably can simplify your filter to something like this

```
getSearchedRow: function() {
    if (this.query.search_column === '')
        return this.model.data;

    return this.model.data.filter(row => {
        const value = row[this.query.search_column];

        // adapt to what your actual operators do
        switch (this.query.search_operator) {
            case 'less_than': return value < this.query.search_input;
            case 'more_than': return value > this.query.search_input;
            // and so on
            default: return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Note that you probaly will have to use a mechanism to cast your values to numbers if you want to get accurate results. For example:

```
data() {
    return {
        model: { data: [
            {id: 1, x: "a", age: 18},
            {id: 2, x: "a", age: 19},
            {id: 3, x: "b", age: 22},
            {id: 4, x: "b", age: 20},
        ] },
        columns: {
          id: {
              cast: function(v) {
                  return +v;
              }
          },
          age: {
              cast: function(v) {
                  return +v;
              }
          }
        },
        query: {
            search_column: 'age',
            search_operator: 'equal',
            search_input: ""
        }
    };
},

computed: {
    getSearchedRow: function() {
        if (this.query.search_column === '')
          return this.model.data;

        const col = this.query.search_column;
        const requiredval = (this.columns[col] && this.columns[col].cast) ? this.columns[col].cast(this.query.search_input) : this.query.search_input;

        return this.model.data.filter(row => {
            const value = row[col];

            switch (this.query.search_operator) {
                case 'less_than': return value < requiredval;
                case 'more_than': return value > requiredval;
                case 'equal': return value === requiredval;

                default: return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And a demo

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            model: { data: [
                {id: 1, x: "a", age: 18},
                {id: 2, x: "a", age: 19},
                {id: 3, x: "b", age: 22},
                {id: 4, x: "b", age: 20},
            ] },
            columns: {
              id: {
                  cast: function(v) {
                      return +v;
                  }
              },
              age: {
                  cast: function(v) {
                      return +v;
                  }
              }
            },
            query: {
                search_column: 'age',
                search_operator: 'equal',
                search_input: ""
            }
        };
    },

    computed: {
        getSearchedRow: function() {
            if (this.query.search_column === '')
              return this.model.data;
        
            const col = this.query.search_column;
            const requiredval = (this.columns[col] && this.columns[col].cast) ? this.columns[col].cast(this.query.search_input) : this.query.search_input;
            
            return this.model.data.filter(row => {
                const value = row[col];
                
                switch (this.query.search_operator) {
                    case 'less_than': return value < requiredval;
                    case 'more_than': return value > requiredval;
                    case 'equal': return value === requiredval;
                    
                    default: return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>


<div id="app">
  <select class="dv-header-select" v-model="query.search_column">
      <option value="">Everything</option>
      <option value="id">ID</option>
      <option value="age">Age</option>
      <option value="x">X</option>
  </select>


  <select class="dv-header-select" v-model="query.search_operator">
      <option value="equal">=</option>
      <option value="less_than">&lt;</option>
      <option value="more_than">&gt;</option>
  </select>

<input type="text" class="dv-header-input" placeholder="Search"
    v-model="query.search_input">

  <table>
    <tr v-for="row in getSearchedRow">
        <td v-for="(value, key) in row">{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function filter(rows, query) {
  return rows.filter(r => {
    if (query.input.length < 1) {
      return true
    }

    if (query.col.length < 1) {
      return true
    }

    const v = r[query.col]
    const i = query.input
    switch (query.op) {
      case '=':
        return v == i
      case '<':
        return v < i
      case '>':
        return v > i
      case '<=':
        return v <= i
      case '>=':
        return v >= i
      default:
        throw "unreachable"
    }
  })
}

const rows = [{
  id: 1,
  age: 20
}, {
  id: 2,
  age: 30
}]
console.log(filter(rows, {
  col: 'id',
  op: '=',
  input: '2'
}))
console.log(filter(rows, {
  col: 'age',
  op: '<',
  input: '25'
}))
console.log(filter(rows, {
  col: '',
  op: '<',
  input: '25'
}))
console.log(filter(rows, {
  col: 'id',
  op: '<',
  input: ''
}))
```

I think your filter logic wrong. Maybe you can try this.