# Javascript comparison bug or am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, comparison

So, I have JS code that is meant to acquire data from server about temperature from 2 sensors. The data is contained in a text file where each line carries date and 2 values each for one thermometer. I have managed to parse this data into arrays of dates and values separately. I can find minimum and maximum value of each array, but when I try to get min and max values from both temperature arrays, I get false data. The temperature values are stored in `data.temperature`, which is an array containing 2 values, each for on of the thermometers (`data` is an array of objects containing a property `temperature`, which as an array of two values). I used a debugger and at multiple points the code threw false when comparing two values which was clearly wrong (19>6=false).

Here is the code:

```
extremes.minTempAbsolute = [0, 0];
for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < data[i].temperature.length; j++){
        if(data[i].temperature[j] < data[extremes.minTempAbsolute[0]].temperature[extremes.minTempAbsolute[1]]){
            extremes.minTempAbsolute = [i, j];
        }
    }
}
```

```
extremes.maxTempAbsolute = [0, 0];
for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < data[i].temperature.length; j++){
        if(data[i].temperature[j] > data[extremes.maxTempAbsolute[0]].temperature[extremes.maxTempAbsolute[1]]){
            extremes.maxTempAbsolute = [i, j];
        }
    }
}
```

Object `extremes` contains indexes of those extremes in `data` array. `minTempAbsolute` and `maxTempAbsolute` contains an array of two indexes - one for `data` and one for `temperature`.

At one point it was comparing `data[i].temperature[j] > data[extremes.maxTempAbsolute[0]].temperature[extremes.maxTempAbsolute[1]]` where `i` was 1540 and `j` was 0 and `maxTempAbsolute[0]` was 460 and `maxTempAbsolute[1]` was 1. Therefore:

```
data[1540].temperature[0] > data[460].temperature[1]
                       19 > 6
                        false
```

When I took these values and logged them in console, it showed me values 19 for the first one and 6 for the second one, but still it would not compare them correctly (as shown above).

My guess is it somehow compares indexes as well because:

```
data[1540].temperature[1] > data[460].temperature[1]
                      6.5 > 6
                        true
```

When the index changed it was comparing just fine.

Please help me. I have tried everything I know and am lost for ideas. Any help will be greatly appreciated. If there are any questions to my problem I will try to answer them promptly.

Comment: do you compare numbers or strings? please verify with `typeof`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript string/integer comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630123/javascript-string-integer-comparisons)

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed it even when I saw those quotes around the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you read the *temperatures* from file, you should use `Number` constructor because you're comparing `strings`.

```
Number(data[1540].temperature[0]) > Number(data[460].temperature[1])
```

Comment: I'd use unary `+` or `parseFloat`, using `parseInt` `3.1 > 3` would be false.

Comment: @6502, you're right. I think `Number` constructor is most suitable here.

Comment: Thanks, I used the `Number` constructor right when I read the value from a file, which solved my problems. I missed it completely though.