# How "2" < "123" is false in Javascript but not 2 < "123"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When I am running the mentioned code. What is the reason behind giving it false and not the second one is it related to ascii value or something else I am Unable to get it.
Can anyone explain this?

```js
console.log('2' < '123');
console.log(2 < '123');
```

Comment: In the first case, strings are compared lexicographically. Meaning character by character. In the second case the 123 is converted to number

Comment: @Etheryte: The question marked as the dupe doesn't contain any reference about the `2 < '123'` case

Comment: dupe regarding string/number comparisons: [Javascript string/integer comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630123/javascript-string-integer-comparisons)

Comment: @DarkBee Yes it does, if you take the time to read more than just the first answer.

Comment: @Etheryte I did read more than just the first answer. From what I can read, the only thing being said bout number to number comparison is `to cast either side to a number`, but in this question both sides are already numbers...

Comment: Should I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [rules for `<`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islessthan) say that:

- (Step 3) If you compare a **string** to a **string**: Compare them lexically.
- (Starting from Step 4c) If you compare a **number** to a **string**: Convert the string to a number, then compare them numerically.

Comment: [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than#description) for additional reference