# if statement evaluating opposite of what it actually is

Tags: javascript, if-statement

If I enter 100 in the input field, the if statement starting on line 149 returns true

(EDIT) I see there are NO line numbers in stackOverflow code blocks, so this is the if statement I am talking about:

```js
if (change > drawer && !set) {
  console.log("Claims that",change,">",drawer);
  set = true;
  cond = 4; //insufficient funds in drawer
}
```

I check the values of change and drawer. (drawer = 335.41. change = 96.74) My console logs all confirm this. if change is greater than drawer the if statement on line 149 should be false, but it evaluates to true, why? there's no way that 335.41 will or can EVER be less than 96.74. I've put logs before, in and after this if statement and at no time are any of those values undefined, so what is the problem? here is my code for script.js:

```js
let price = 3.26;
let cid = [
  ["PENNY", 1.01],
  ["NICKEL", 2.05],
  ["DIME", 3.1],
  ["QUARTER", 4.25],
  ["ONE", 90],
  ["FIVE", 55],
  ["TEN", 20],
  ["TWENTY", 60],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
];
let cash;
let messages = ["Status: OPEN", "Status: CLOSED", "Status: INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS"];
let cond;
let change;
let drawer;
let str = "";
let numberOfUnits = 0;
let multiplier = Float32Array.from([0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 1, 5, 10, 20, 100]);
let purchaseBtn = document.getElementById("purchase-btn");
let changeDue = document.getElementById("change-due");
let itemPrice = document.getElementById("item-price");
let denominant = document.getElementById("change");
let clearBtn = document.getElementById("clear-btn");
let unit = Int32Array.from([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
let numIn = document.getElementById("cash");
let ap = document.getElementById("amountP");
let an = document.getElementById("amountN");
let ad = document.getElementById("amountD");
let aq = document.getElementById("amountQ");
let ar = document.getElementById("amountR");
let af = document.getElementById("amountF");
let ae = document.getElementById("amountE");
let at = document.getElementById("amountT");
let ah = document.getElementById("amountH");
let hp = document.getElementById("haveP");
let hn = document.getElementById("haveN");
let hd = document.getElementById("haveD");
let hq = document.getElementById("haveQ");
let hr = document.getElementById("haveR");
let hf = document.getElementById("haveF");
let he = document.getElementById("haveE");
let ht = document.getElementById("haveT");
let hh = document.getElementById("haveH");
let gp = document.getElementById("giveP");
let gn = document.getElementById("giveN");
let gd = document.getElementById("giveD");
let gq = document.getElementById("giveQ");
let gr = document.getElementById("giveR");
let gf = document.getElementById("giveF");
let ge = document.getElementById("giveE");
let gt = document.getElementById("giveT");
let gh = document.getElementById("giveH");
changeDue.setAttribute("readonly", true);
itemPrice.setAttribute("readonly", true);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  populator();
});

function populator() {
  gp.innerHTML = unit[0]; gn.innerHTML = unit[1]; gd.innerHTML = unit[2]; gq.innerHTML = unit[3];
  gr.innerHTML = unit[4]; gf.innerHTML = unit[5]; ge.innerHTML = unit[6]; gt.innerHTML = unit[7]; gh.innerHTML = unit[8];
  ap.innerHTML = "$ " + cid[0][1].toFixed(2);an.innerHTML = "$ " + cid[1][1].toFixed(2);ad.innerHTML = "$ " + cid[2][1].toFixed(2); 
  aq.innerHTML = "$ " + cid[3][1].toFixed(2);ar.innerHTML = "$ " + cid[4][1].toFixed(2);af.innerHTML = "$ " + cid[5][1].toFixed(2);
  ae.innerHTML = "$ " + cid[6][1].toFixed(2);at.innerHTML = "$ " + cid[7][1].toFixed(2);ah.innerHTML = "$ " + cid[8][1].toFixed(2);
  hp.innerHTML = Math.floor(cid[0][1] / multiplier[0]);hn.innerHTML = Math.floor(cid[1][1] / multiplier[1]);
  hd.innerHTML = Math.floor(cid[2][1] / multiplier[2]);hq.innerHTML = Math.floor(cid[3][1] / multiplier[3]);
  hr.innerHTML = Math.floor(cid[4][1] / multiplier[4]);hf.innerHTML = Math.floor(cid[5][1] / multiplier[5]); 
  he.innerHTML = Math.floor(cid[6][1] / multiplier[6]);ht.innerHTML = Math.floor(cid[7][1] / multiplier[7]); 
  hh.innerHTML = Math.floor(cid[8][1] / multiplier[8]);
  itemPrice.value = price;
  drawer = (Number(cid[0][1]) + Number(cid[1][1]) + Number(cid[2][1]) + Number(cid[3][1]) + Number(cid[4][1])  + Number(cid[5][1]) + Number(cid[6][1]) + Number(cid[7][1]) + Number(cid[8][1])).toFixed(2);
}

function moneyIn(cashDistributor) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    while (cashDistributor >= Number(multiplier[8 - i])) {
      cid[8 - i][1] = cid[8 - i][1] + Number(multiplier[8 - i].toFixed(2));
      cashDistributor -= Number(multiplier[8 - i]);
    }
  }
  populator();
}

function dividender () {
    for (let i = 8; i > 0; i--) {
        numberOfUnits = Math.floor(cid[i][1] % change) / Number(multiplier[i]);
        console.log(cid[i][0], ": ", cid[i][1], ", Units: ", numberOfUnits);
        if (numberOfUnits > 0) {
            unit[i] = numberOfUnits;
            cid[i][1] -= (unit[i] * Number(multiplier[i]));
            change -= (unit[i] * Number(multiplier[i]));
            let hold = (unit[i] * Number(multiplier[i])).toFixed(2);
            str += (cid[i][0] + ": $" + hold + " ");
        }
    }
    if (change < 0.01){
        cond = 0;
    } else cond = 2;
}

function update () {  
  if(cond < 4) {
      moneyIn(cash);
      denominant.style.display = "inline";
      denominant.style.border = "1px solid #ad2";
      denominant.style.width = "346px";
      denominant.style.overflow = "hidden";
  }
    if (cond < 2) {changeDue.innerHTML = messages[cond] + " " + str;}
    if (cond === 2) {changeDue.innerHTML = messages[cond];}
    if (cond === 3) {changeDue.innerHTML = "No change due - customer paid with exact cash";}
    if (cond === 4) {changeDue.innerHTML = messages[2] + " " + str;}
    if (cond === 5) {changeDue.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid number";}
    if (cond === 6) {alert("Customer does not have enough money to purchase the item");}
}

purchaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  str = "";
  unit = Int32Array.from([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
  cash = (parseFloat(numIn.value == undefined ? "" : numIn.value.trim())).toFixed(2);
  change = (cash - price).toFixed(2);
  console.log("change:",change,", drawer:",drawer);
  let set = false;
  if (!cash && !set) {
    set = true;
    cond = 5;//no value entered
  } 
  if (cash < price && !set) {
    set = true;
    cond = 6;//customer doesn't have enough money
  }
  if (change > drawer && !set) {
    console.log("Claims that",change,">",drawer);
    set = true;
    cond = 4; //insufficient funds in drawer
  }
  if (cash == price && !set) {
    set = true;
    cond = 3;//paid with exact amount
  }
  if (change == drawer && !set) {
    set = true;
    cond = 1;//register closed with a ballance of 0
    dividender();
  }
  if (change < drawer && !set) {//Normal transaction
    set = true;
    dividender();   
  }
  update(cond);
  populator();
});

clearBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  changeDue.innerHTML = "";
  itemPrice.value = price;
  cash = 0;
  numIn.value = "";
  str = "";
  unit = Int32Array.from([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
  numberOfUnits = 0;
  denominant.style.border = "none";
  denominant.style.display = "none";
});
```

And here is index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <title>ffcCashRegister</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><p title="Don't shortchange yourself or the customer" >Cash register</p></h1>
    <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Item Price: $
      <input type="input" id="item-price" value="1.87">
      <button id="purchase-btn">Buy Item</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="child">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Amount tendered:
    <input type="input" id="cash">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="child">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Customer's change:
      <div id="change-due"></div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="child">
    <button id="clear-btn">CLEAR ALL</button>
    </div>
      <div id="change" class="child">
       <table id="change-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Currency Unit</th>
    <th>Give customer</th>
    <th>Currency Unit</th>
    <th>Give customer</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="th1">Penny</td>
    <td id="giveP">0</td>
    <td id="th1">Five Dollars</td>
    <td id="giveF">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="th1">Nickle</td>
    <td id="giveN">0</td>
    <td id="th1">Ten Dollars</td>
    <td id="giveE">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="th1">Dime</td>
    <td id="giveD">0</td>
    <td id="th1">Twenty Dollars</td>
    <td id="giveT">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="th1">Quarter</td>
    <td id="giveQ">0</td>
    <td id="th1">One Hundred Dollars</td>
    <td id="giveH">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="th1">Dollar</td>
    <td id="giveR">0</td>
    <td id="th1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="give">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <br>
    <div id="status" >
      <table id="status-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Currency Unit</th>
    <th>$$$ Value</th>
    <th>Count</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Penny</td>
    <td id="amountP">$1.01</td>
    <td id="haveP">101</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nickle</td>
    <td id="amountN">$2.05</td>
    <td id="haveN">41</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dime</td>
    <td id="amountD">$3.10</td>
    <td id="haveD">31</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Quarter</td>
    <td id="amountQ">$4.25</td>
    <td id="haveQ">17</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dollar</td>
    <td id="amountR">$90.00</td>
    <td id="haveR">90</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Five Dollars</td>
    <td id="amountF">$55.00</td>
    <td id="haveF">11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ten Dollars</td>
    <td id="amountE">$20</td>
    <td id="haveE">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Twenty Dollars</td>
    <td id="amountT">$60</td>
    <td id="haveT">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One Hundred Dollars</td>
    <td id="amountH">$100</td>
    <td id="haveH">1</td>
  </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
      
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the styles.css file:

```css
* {
  font-size: 20px;
}
html, body {
  height: 130%; 
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(221, 218, 34);
  background-color: rgb(129, 64, 3);
}
body {
  color:rgb(55, 248, 184);
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #ad2;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid #ad2;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid #ad2;
}
#th1 {
    background-color: rgb(38, 92, 0);
    color:rgb(55, 248, 184);
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    outline-style: dotted;
    outline-width: 2px;
    outline-color: rgb(255, 215, 0);
}

p {
    color:rgb(55, 248, 184);
    width: 175;
    margin: auto; 
}
.child {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 9;
  }
  
  .child p {
    margin: 10;
  }

  #change{
    border: 1px solid #ad2;
    width: 346px;
    padding-right: 250px;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  #change-table{
    border: 1px solid #ad2;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #status{
    border: 1px solid #ad2;
    width: 246px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #status-table{
    border: 1px solid #ad2;
    text-align: center;
  }


#purchase-btn {
    border: 1px solid #ad2;
    background-color: orange;
    color:rgb(23, 95, 71);
    width: 112px;
    margin: 10px; 
}

#clear-btn {
    border: 1px solid #ad2;
    background-color: orange;
    color:rgb(23, 95, 71);
    width: 112px;
    margin: 10px; 
}

#change-due {
  background-color: rgb(160,111,54);
  color:rgb(55, 248, 184);
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#change-due:focus {
  background-color: rgb(165,134,99);
  color:rgb(55, 248, 184);
}

#cash {
    border: 1px solid #ad2;
    background-color: rgb(160,111,54);
    color:rgb(55, 248, 184);
    width: 260px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#cash:focus {
  border: 1px solid #ad2; 
  background-color: rgb(165,134,99);
  color:rgb(55, 248, 184);
}

#item-price{
  border: 1px solid #ad2;
  background-color: rgb(160,111,54);
  color:rgb(55, 248, 184);
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#item-price:focus {
  border: 1px solid #ad2;
  background-color: rgb(165,134,99);
  color:rgb(55, 248, 184);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `set` (I assume `false`, but show it anyhow), the value of `change > drawer`, and the value of `change > drawer && !set`? Put them all in variables (or an array), and see the results. If the latter two don't match, then there's an error in your assumptions. Also note, `"99.99" > "321.11"` is `true`.

Comment: Probably relevant:  [Javascript string/integer comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630123/javascript-string-integer-comparisons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably string comparison:

```js
console.log(335.41 > 96.74)
console.log('335.41' > '96.74')
console.log(Number('335.41') > Number('96.74'))
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that is what it ended up being, I added Number to the change and drawer variables before comparing them and the if statement blocks work correctly now, thank you

Comment: @OP Rather than converting on the fly, you might want to address what made things that should be numbers into strings. Note that `.toFixed(2)` turns a javascript number into a string, but it doesn't necessarily improve the precision of your number (in fact, it may make your calculations _worse_). You should only use that when you're outputting a number for display, less you come to find that `"1" + 1 == 11 == "11"`. Don't mix the two.